# notepad++ remove a text that not contains spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a string such as `"brown,Ceilings,flu,hydraulic bar stool,horse saddles,marble tiles"`. I want to remove the text that does not contain spaces, but keep the text that has at least one space. The result should be like `hydraulic bar stool,horse saddles,marble tiles`.

I'm stuck at `[^,]*\s` and still how to figure out the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
(^|,)[^ ,]+(,|$)
```

Replace with

```
\1
```

Comment: the `Ceilings` still apprear

Comment: I just tried it - Replace dialog, Regular expression checked, Replace All - and the result is "hydraulic bar stool,horse saddles,marble tiles" without Ceilings

Comment: Yes you are right.. my bad.. last time I just did test with www.regexr.com .. so sorry for my mistake. You Rock !

Comment: Both of you give me the correct answers, but I only can give one.. to who I should give the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `(^|,)\w+,`
Replace with: `$1`

Make sure `Regular Expresion` is checked.

Comment: it's also the `Ceilings` still apprear

Comment: @user3670443: It works well here. Have you clicked on `Replace all` button?

Comment: So sorry.. Yes you are correct too.. as I said in the top comment .. I just test with www.regexr.com